# How can I improve this Pandas DataFrame construction?

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote this ugly piece of code. It does the job, but it is not elegant. Any suggestion to improve it?

Function returns a dict given i, j.

```
pairs = [dict({"i":i, "j":j}.items() + function(i, j).items()) for i,j in my_iterator]
pairs = pd.DataFrame(pairs).set_index(['i', 'j'])
```

The `dict({}.items() + function(i, j).items())` is supposed to merge both dict in one as `dict().update()` does not return the merged dict.

Comment: could you include an example (my_iterator, function)?

Comment: @AndyHayden my_iterator is simply itertools.combinations(range(some_constant),2) and my_function is a thin wrapper to an R function using RPy2 taking two pandas series in input: data[i] and data[j], returning a dictionnary with various stat results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A favourite trick* to return an updated a newly created dictionary:

```
dict(i=i, j=j, **function(i, j))
```

**and of much [debate on whether this is actually "valid"](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1061583?do=post_view_threaded#1061583)...*

Perhaps also worth mentioning the DataFrame `from_records` method:

```
In [11]: my_iterator = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_iterator, columns=['i', 'j'])

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   i  j
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

I suspect there would be a more efficient method by vectorizing your function (but it's hard to say what makes more sense without more specifics of your situation)...

Comment: On a side note,it would cleaner to do `dict(i=i, j=j, **function(i, j))`, instead of `dict([("i", i), ("j",j)], **function(i, j))`.

Comment: Also, why wouldn't it be "valid"? I'm curious because I've never run across any resistance to it before, and it's an at-least-somewhat-common idiom...

Comment: @JoeKington because the dictionary can contain some keys which are not valid keywords (the correct terminology escapes me at the moment). I like it, and use it often.

Comment: @JoeKington see http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1061583?do=post_view_threaded#1061583

Comment: @JoeKington I suppose "much" was an exaggeration... only a tiny bit of debate.

Comment: @AndyHayden @Joe I was able to use your answer before you edited it. Using this function: `def foo(i, j): return dict({str(j):i})`, the following returns a SyntaxError `[dict("i"=i, "j"=j, **foo(i,j)) for i,j in combinations('ABC',2)]` where `[dict([("i", i), ("j",j)], **foo(i, j)) for i,j in combinations('ABC',2)]` does work.

Comment: @AndyHayden - It was because `dict("i"=i)` is invalid syntax. It should have been `dict(i=i)`.

Comment: @JoeKington - thanks, I edited Andy's answer to match your syntax (currently under peer review).